# Chaining terminal commands in .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, .bash-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On a Mac, how can I group together commands I want run into a alias?](https://superuser.com/questions/285417/on-a-mac-how-can-i-group-together-commands-i-want-run-into-a-alias)

I have been using aliases for a while now but can't seem to figure out how to 'chain' commands properly. For instance, is there a way to type in one alias and have it chain multiple commands, like this?

```
'cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/V3/wp-content/themes/V3/'
mate .
open /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/
open -a Safari http://localhost:8888/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use shell functions:

```
function mampMate() {
    cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/V3/wp-content/themes/V3/
    mate .
    open /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/
    open -a Safari http://localhost:8888/
}
```

Add these to your `.bash_profile` and run by entering

```
mampMate
```

---

You can even pass parameters and access them using their index as `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
function foo() {
    echo "1: $1"
    echo "2: $2"
}

$ foo bar baz
1: bar
2: baz
```

---

One step further, and making your script more independent of your preferred shell, are scripts. Create a file named `mampMate.sh` and add the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/V3/wp-content/themes/V3/
mate .
open /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/
open -a Safari http://localhost:8888/
```

This won't change your working directory though, as it won't affect your shell session.

Run `chmod +x mampMate.sh` and place it in a directory on your `$PATH`.